# match if url is starting with certain characters

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter

I am developing a project in codeigniter, I don't have much knowledge of regular expression. I want to check a url in codeigniter route.

This is my url example

`single-user-abc-name-1540`

The single-user is static here. I want to check this is route file.

**Code i Have tried:**

```
$route['single-user-([A-Za-z0-9]+)'] = 'mycontroller/test';
```

Also I have googled but no solution find it.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Did you try: `$route['single-user-([A-Za-z0-90]+)'] = 'mycontroller/test';`

Comment: Yes, but still 404 page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a dash `-`  in your character class:

```
single-user-[A-Za-z0-9-]+'
#              here __^
```